# What does [!E] mean in the name of a Trello board?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

A few of our Trello boards have `[!E]` added at the end of the board name. No one in the team added this manually so I'm assuming this is added automatically somehow.

Any ideas what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this myself recently. The [!E] is derived from the Board owner using the [*Elagantt*](https://elegantt.com/) Chrome app with Trello.

Comment: Welcome. It's not necessary to include a post signature as all post include a standard user card. Ref. [Expected behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Thanks. Turns out a colleague was using Elagannt but didn't 'click' that that was the cause.